# Check status of running php script

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

### Short Background:

My database will have a list of emails, and the user will create pricesheets to send to those customer's emails. I would like this to happen at the click of a button to make sure that the pricesheets are correct before sending rather than setting up a CRON job to handle this for me.

### The Process

I am using Codeigniter, and a Linux server on a remote host.

1. User clicks a button to start the process. Set db column status to the PID I get in my model.
2. AJAX call the controller function. This runs until it has finished emailing out the customers. (dummy sleep function for now).
3. When script finishes (HTTP request is fulfilled), ajax removes the processing icon.

   - If the user visits the page after the script has started, if status != 0, loops to HTTP request the controller to check the status of the PID.
   - I'm noticing that the PID I'm getting is always 5012, and in my script seems to always be running.
   - I'm running `if (shell_exec("ps aux | grep " . $pid . " | wc -l") > 0) { // PID is running }` as my check if the process is running, where $pid is a parameter of the function.

### Last Steps to make this all come together:

- If a user visits the page and the script is running, I don't have a way to see if and when the script completes
- I don't want to brute query the DB because that seems like it would be a performance issue later
- I would eventually like to add a static icon to the site so the user doesn't have to return here to check the status

## TLDR

I'm running a PHP script within codeigniter, and need a way that when I visit a different page, or refresh the current one, I can check if the script is still running or not for proper user feedback.

Comment: You've described a scenario you want to create, but haven't really described your problem.  This site isn't a 'how do I do my idea' site.  It's to help solve specific issues.  Can you edit this to be more specific about what you are having trouble with and what you have already tried to solve that problem?

Comment: I guess I didn't make it as obvious as I could have, The issue is that the check I am doing `(shell_exec("ps aux | grep " . $pid . " | wc -l") > 0)` seems to return a false positive every time because the only pid I can get is that of PHP, so if a PHP script is running, of course it will return TRUE

Comment: What's the command you used to run the process?

Comment: I'm executing the PHP script via HTTP request, so just visiting the URL I suppose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to avoid using a db because of performance, but somewhere you need a flag or other way of identifying that the script is running.  PHP sessions are out since someone viewing it from another session wouldn't have the same flag set.

Try using something faster than a DB - like memcache.

```
<?php
// if memcache->is_running is set
    // echo some response message saying it's running and exit
// set memcache->is_running w/ the start time maybe
// ... your code
// write memcache->is_running start timestamp and end timestamp to db or file
// clear memcache->is_running
```

Comment: full disclosure, the client of this project doesn't have a VPS and would not be able to use memcache, but it is a valid suggestion